# Is there a way to deactivate (but not delete) conditional breakpoints when debugging?

Tags: debugging, pycharm, spyder, visual-studio-debugging, conditional-breakpoint

It might be easy to just turn them off if it's a regular breakpoint, but sometimes I want to just deactivate the conditional breakpoint for a while, and have the option to turn it back (with the conditional still being written out so I don't have to retype it again). Do any of these IDE's have this capability?

Comment: please ask your question on a per-IDE basis. you can split this question post into three question posts.

Comment: @starball Is this the case though since I'm wondering just if any of them have this feature? Should I change it to "is there an IDE which supports ...?"